# Exporting large Video from an app with no free space on internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-transfer, sony-xperia, data-transfer

I have a large (4gb) video currently stored in an app called KeepSafe. My phone (Sony Xperia Z3 has 8gb internal memory and a 128gb SD card. However the internal memory is almost full (only 400mb free). KeepSafe is an app that stores photos/videos, hidden behind a pin. ie it stores them in an internal database.

I need to get this video off my internal memory and either onto the SD card or onto my computer. The problem is when I try to "unhide" it in the KeepSafe app, the thumbnail goes cloudy for a half hour or so (I assume this indicates it's processing) but then doesn't seem to unhide, and then seems to remain in KeepSafe. I'm assuming this might be because the phone is so full.

I was wondering if KeepSafe may require there to be some sort of free space buffer in order to unhide it?

It's very important I get this content off the phone in any way possible. Is there any way I can do this? Can I perhaps move the entire KeepSafe database from internal memory onto the SD card? If there is any way to achieve this I will do it.

Comment: Fair call. I adjusted the wording of the question to give a bit more context.

I'm new to android stackexchange. Is this question too app-specific for this site?

Comment: Okay. That's acceptable. But, is your phone rooted or not?

Comment: It's not rooted, no. However I believe the data is stored in a folder called .keepsafe

Comment: Is this the app ? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kii.safe

Comment: That's the one yeah. And there is a support site at http://support.getkeepsafe.com/ - i have logged a request at http://support.getkeepsafe.com/hc/en-us/requests/1560783 but doesn't seem like any response which is why I tried here

Comment: There is no such kind of thing like a free space buffer. For transferring a file, most apps need a temporary directory containing a small file (~40MB) to act as a mediator while transferring files. Since you say you have 400MB free, that must be no problem. I'll just do some research and get back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23171/discussion-between-rjt-rockx-and-manachi).